# How can I type a resulting function based on the return type of an argument function

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics

I have two functions:

```
export const processCar = (params: IParams): Car => {
    // ...
}

export const processBoat = (params: IParams): Boat => {
    // ...
}
```

I have another function to which the first two functions will be passed as arguments:

```
const processOrNull = (func: any): any => {
    const newFunc = (params: IParams): any => {
        // Perform some check. If it fails, return null. If it passes...

        return func(params);
    }
    return newFunc;
}

export const processCarOrNull = processOrNull(processCar);  // (IParams) => Car | null;
export const processBoatOrNull = processOrNull(processBoat);    // (IParams) => Boat | null;
```

I want the result from processOrNull to be typed as either `(IParams) => (Car | null)` or `(IParams) => (Boat | null)`, depending on whether the passed function returns a Car or a Boat.

Can I do this with generics and if so, how?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cant use the function directly? (eg: processCar(), processBoat()) As when you trigger processOrNull() you already know what function you are passing. So the processOrNull seems to add superfluous complexity. Hard to understand exactly what is required from that small amount of code, but I reckon there is probably a better way of achieving what you need. You don't need generics as you are passing a function object for either option.

Comment: Do you want to return ((IParams) => Boat) | null or (IParams) => (Boat | null)

Comment: (IParams) => (Boat | null). Edited my question to clarify.